# ToElementMesh fails on DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, mesh, finite-element-method, polyhedra

**Context**

I would like to compute the eigenmodes of a `DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound`.

*Why?* Because it is cool! and I wonder how it rings…

Starting with:

```
 R = DiscretizeGraphics@
  PolyhedronData["DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[R]
```

I get:

> $FAILED
>   ToBoundaryMesh::femtemnm: A mesh could not be generated. >>

**Question**

> why does [`ToElementMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToElementMesh.html)
>   fail on this graphics?

Comment: I get: ToBoundaryMesh::fememib: The input has or generated an intersecting boundary and cannot be processed. Maybe you want to update to V 10.1.

Comment: @user21 so it does NOT work for you either?

Comment: Yes, and that is expected and the message states why this is the case.

Comment: Note that `PolyhedronData["DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound"]` consists of an intersecting dodecahedron and icosahedron.

Comment: @user21 You might be interested in the comment below my answer.  I'm not sure whether or not it indicates a bug.  The error message is rather obscure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `PolyhedronData["DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound"]` consists of an intersecting dodecahedron and icosahedron:

```
PolyhedronData["DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound"] /. 
 Polygon[p_] :> {Opacity[0.6], 
   Riffle[{Red, LightBlue}, Polygon /@ SplitBy[p, Length]]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A fix is to cut out the middles of the faces of the dodecahedron and icosahedron.

```
polyMinusMiddle[polypts_List] := 
 With[{pts = Partition[polypts, 3, 1, 1]},
  Transpose[{{1/2, 1/2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1/2}}.Transpose@pts]
  ]

g = First@ Normal@ PolyhedronData["DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound"] /. 
   Polygon -> Polygon@* polyMinusMiddle;

pts = DeleteDuplicates@
   Cases[g, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity];
nf = Nearest[N@pts -> Automatic];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> pts,
   "BoundaryElements" -> 
    Flatten[g /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} :> 
        First@nf[{x, y, z}] /. Polygon[p_] :> TriangleElement@ p]
   ];

emesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh]
(*
ElementMesh[{{-1.51152, 1.51152}, {-1.30902, 1.30902}, {-1.40126, 1.40126}},
 {TetrahedronElement["<" 3837 ">"]}]
*)
```

Visualization:

```
MeshRegion@ emesh
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And it is a quadratic mesh, which is good for solving PDEs:

```
emesh["MeshOrder"]
(*  2  *)
```

Comment: Note: `ToElementMesh` on `DiscretizeGraphics@Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, g /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} :> First@nf[{x, y, z}]]]` yields a "TetGenTetrahedralize::reterr: Tetrahedralize returned an error, 2. >>" error.

Comment: Good job! I'll look at the message tomorrow. Thanks.